# Can't reinstall Mac OS X El Capitan because the only partition is a locked OS X Base Image taking up the full HDD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, ssd

I'm trying to reinstall Mac OS X El Capitan on a new Macbook Air. Disk Utility lists a single SSD with a capacity of 251GB and a single partition (OS X Base system) that is taking up 250.4GB. When I try to create another partition it says that I need to enable journaling, but the option is greyed out. I also can't reinstall from the internet because the OS X Base System partition is locked.

Any ideas?

Edit: As requested by @klanomath

[image]

Comment: Please boot to (Internet) Recovery Mode, open Terminal.app in the menubar Utilities > Terminal.app. Enter `gpt -r show disk0` and `df`, take a pic (with a phone/camera) and add it to your question

Comment: Alright, added to question.

Comment: If you didn't do it already, with `Internet Recovery > Utilities > Disk Utility`, select your physical SSD and run a `First Aid`. Eventually turn down the `► Show Details`.  I suspect your SSD (`disk0`) to have problems.

Comment: @Keysmack Your Recovery HD somehow vanished (it should be a third partition in the 158692 blocks gap following disk0s2). Boot to Internet Recovery Mode (alt-cmd-R) and try to erase the main disk (not the volume1) with Disk Utility. Then reinstall OS X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an OCRed version of the screenshot (it may contain small errors):

```
-bash-3.2#  gpt -r show disk0
     start      size  index contents
         0         1            PMBR
         1         1            Pri GPT header
         2         4            Pri GPT table
         6     76800      1     GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     76806  61043841      2     GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  61120647    158692        
  61279339         4            Sec GPT table
  61279343         1            Sec GPT header
-bash-3.2# df
Filesystem     512-blocks      Used Available Capacity   iused     ifree    %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2    488350728   2506264 485332464     1%    377281  60666558       1%   /
devfs                 374       374         0   100%       648         0     100%   /dev
/dev/disk1          10240     10240         0   100%      1278         0     100%   /private/var/log
/dev/disk2           1024       288       736    29%        34        92      27%   /Volumes
/dev/disk3           1024       296       728    29%        35        91      28%   /private/var/tmp
/dev/disk4           1024       312       712    31%        37        89      29%   /private/var/run
/dev/disk5           1024       280       744    28%        33        93      26%   /System/Installation
/dev/disk6           1024       504       520    50%        61        65      48%   /private/var/db
/dev/disk7          12288      6552      5736    54%       817       111      53%   /private/var/folders
/dev/disk8           4096       448      3648    11%        54       456      11%   /private/var/root/Library
/dev/disk10          1024       328       696    33%        39        87      31%   /Library/Preferences
/dev/disk11          1024       312       712    31%        37        89      29%   /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
/dev/disk12          2048       280      1768    14%        33       221      13%   /Library/Keychains
/dev/disk13         12288      1712     10576    14%       212      1322      14%   /private/var/tmp/RecoveryTemp
```

On your main disk a third partition usually containing the Recovery HD is completely missing: the line in the *gpt* output starting with 61120647 should look like this:

```
     61120647     158692      3     GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
```

Instead the content of Base OS X image (usually residing on the Recovery HD partition) seems to be written to disk0s2 as visible in the *df* output:

```
/dev/disk0s2    488350728   2506264 485332464     1%    377281  60666558
```

The occupied 2506264 (512) blocks are roughly equal to the size of a decompressed Base OS X: 1.2 GB.

The content of *Base OS X* probably got copied to your main volume somehow. Booted to this volume, any attempt to erase the disk or volume will fail.

---

To solve your problem boot to Internet Recovery Mode (hold <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting) and open *Disk Utility*.

Choose the superior SSD disk (and not the inferior volume) and hit the erase button. Choose a name, OS X Extended (journaled) and the GUID partition scheme.

If this fails for whatever reason open *Terminal* in the menubar Utilities > Terminal. Enter `diskutil list` to get the disk identifier of the internal disk (probably disk0 - below I assume it's disk0)

Then enter `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ "Macintosh HD" disk0`. If this fails also, hammer the stubborn SSD with either:

```
diskutil umountDisk disk0
gpt detroy disk0
gpt create -f disk0
```

or

```
diskutil umountDisk disk0
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0 bs=4096 count=6
```

Be sure that it's disk0 though!

Now enter `exit` and quit *Terminal*. Open *Disk Utility* again and partition the disk like described previously.

Quit *Disk Utility* and in the Utilities window open *Restore OS X* and follow the instructions..

Comment: Which OCR tool?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you it’s woeking so far fingers crossed

Comment: My mid2010 Mac Mini was locked up in the OS Base X and I used your "Terminal" instructions & now I have macOS High Sierra and all seems well. Thank you very much.